# Tracking for convention badge

Tags: feature-request, badges

Seeing as the Convention badge is required for running in the [moderation election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9)

[image]

We should add the Convention badge to the badges page viewable from the metadata profile page

Comment: I posted this same question 40 mins ago, but some how it's dissappeared from my questions queue and this page what a mystery

Comment: @Kendra this is a feature request not a discussion(like the question you've provided)

Comment: @Kendra yup your right, this question is closed now